# Working with symmetric polynomials

Tags: symbolic, polynomials

I have a question related to working with symmetric polynomials in some variables.
Let us say, I have an expression

```
expr = x^2 + y^2 + 2*x^3 + 2*y^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 y^2 x
```

this is symmetric as `x <-> y`

I want to express this as `expr1 + expr2` where

```
expr1 = x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 y
```

and

```
expr2 = expr1/.{x -> y, y-> x}
```

How to use *Mathematica* to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something in the question, but `Together[expr]` gives what you want.

Comment: What distinguishes your target expressions from, say, `expr1=expr2=expr/2`? The two add up to your original expression and can be obtained from each other by doing `x`$\leftrightarrow$`y`. The class of functions that does that is rather broad! How do you pick your target from within that?

Answer (score 4):

The original question is not clear. There is a wide range of functionality to work with polynomials symbolically e.g. `PolynomialReduce`, `SymmetricReduction`, etc. however it is not clear why one just assumes that `expr1` and `expr2` are as given above and if they are **unique representants** of possible reductions in terms of third order polynomials of two variables, most likely they are not.
So I find that this question is asking: how can I find **appropriate coefficients** `{a, b, c}` such that `expr == p[x,y] + p[y,x]` where:

```
p[x_, y_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x y^2
```

There is `SolveAlways` which helps in such cases:

```
{p[x, y], p[y, x]} /. SolveAlways[ expr == p[x, y] + p[y, x], {x, y}]
```

> ```
>  {{x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x y^2, 3 x^2 y + y^2 + 2 y^3}}
> ```

`PolynomialReduce` demonstrates that `expr1` and `expr2` can express the original polynomial `expr`

```
PolynomialReduce[ expr, {expr1, expr2}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, 0}
> ```

`SymmetricReduction` serves a different purpose, see e.g.

```
SymmetricReduction[expr, {x, y}, {expr1, expr2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to make a Groebner basis from the polynomials that define the relationships you intend to apply ("reduce with", if you will), and then do that with `PolynomialReduce`.

```
poly = x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 y;
polys = {poly - e1, (poly /. {x -> y, y -> x}) - e2};
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, {x, y}];
```

Now for the example in question.

```
expr = x^2 + y^2 + 2*x^3 + 2*y^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 y^2 x;
PolynomialReduce[expr, gb, {x, y}][[2]]

(* e1 + e2 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using knowledge from [`CoefficientList` docs (Properties and Relations section)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientList.html) of how to recreate multivariate polynomial from coefficient list:

```
coe = CoefficientList[expr, {x, y}][[ All , ;; 2]];

expr1 = Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, coe, {x, y}] // Expand

expr2 = expr1 /. {x -> y, y -> x}
```

> ```
> x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 y
> y^2 + 3 x y^2 + 2 y^3
> ```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is :

```
expr = x^2 + y^2 + 2*x^3 + 2*y^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 y^2 x;

expr1 = x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 y;

expr2 = expr1 /. {x -> y, y -> x}

expr1 + expr2 == expr
```

Another way is to define functions :

```
expr1[x_,y_]:=x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 y;
expr2[x_,y_]:=expr1[y,x];
```