# Collecting terms in an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

I have an expression:

```
(C1*R*(10*k12*k21 - 20*k11*k22 - k21^2*Cos[4*t] + 10*k11^2 + 10*k12^2 + 3*k21^2 + 10*k22^2 - 
 4*k12*k21*Cos[2*t] - 2*k12*k21*Cos[4*t] + 4*k11*k21*Sin[2*t] + 2*k11*k21*Sin[4*t] - 
 4*k21*k22*Sin[2*t] - 2*k21*k22*Sin[4*t]))/32
```

and I would like to factor this in terms of squares of the `k`s. (e.g., `(k12^2 - k21^2)`, `(k22 - k11)^2`, `(k12 + k21)^2`, etc.)

If the trigonometric identities can be simplified, then that's perfect. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

From [Daniel Lichtblau's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) answer, [Working with symmetric polynomials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/working-with-symmetric-polynomials/43383#43383), it's easy to do as much as is specified.  I interpret "factor" to mean "write in terms of," but I'm not sure exactly what quadratic terms are implied.

```
subs = {q1 -> (k12^2 - k21^2), q2 -> (k22 - k11)^2, q3 -> (k12 + k21)^2};
polys = Subtract @@@ subs;
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, {x, y}];

expr = (C1*
     R*(10*k12*k21 - 20*k11*k22 - k21^2*Cos[4*t] + 10*k11^2 + 10*k12^2 + 
       3*k21^2 + 10*k22^2 - 4*k12*k21*Cos[2*t] - 2*k12*k21*Cos[4*t] + 
       4*k11*k21*Sin[2*t] + 2*k11*k21*Sin[4*t] - 4*k21*k22*Sin[2*t] - 
       2*k21*k22*Sin[4*t]))/32;
PolynomialReduce[expr, gb, {k11, k12, k21, k22}][[2]]
```

---

If you want *Mathematica* to find some way to express `expr` in terms of quadratic expressions in the `k`s, create a list `qs` of the possible forms you would consider acceptable and create variables `q[i]`, `i = 1, ...` up to the number of forms in `qs`. Then the above method will find a solution, but it won't be unique.

```
ks = {k11, k12, k21, k22};
qs = Flatten@
   MapThread[{#1^2 - #2^2, #1^2 + #2^2, (#1 - #2)^2, (#1 + #2)^2} &, 
    Transpose@Subsets[ks, {2}]];
subs = Thread[Array[q, Length@qs] -> qs];
polys = Subtract @@@ subs;
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, {x, y}];

expr = (C1*
     R*(10*k12*k21 - 20*k11*k22 - k21^2*Cos[4*t] + 10*k11^2 + 
       10*k12^2 + 3*k21^2 + 10*k22^2 - 4*k12*k21*Cos[2*t] - 
       2*k12*k21*Cos[4*t] + 4*k11*k21*Sin[2*t] + 2*k11*k21*Sin[4*t] - 
       4*k21*k22*Sin[2*t] - 2*k21*k22*Sin[4*t]))/32;
quadReduced = PolynomialReduce[expr, gb, {k11, k12, k21, k22}~Join~Array[q, Length@qs]][[2]]
```

Use

```
quadReduce /. subs
```

to get `expr` back.

Comment: thanks for your answer...it helps a lot..i was wondering if it may be possible to write the above expression in terms of squares of the k's without actually myself defining them (I have some other onerous expressions and I wanted to simplify them in this fashion -- i don't really know the end product of these). Any other advice would be much appreciated. thanks again

Comment: Which squares of the `k`'s?  I don't see the pattern -- the three are all different.

Comment: oh..i meant that the expressions themselves (i.e., those in subs) should be found automatically without me having to actually pre-define them -- for any expression...is this possible? it was just that i kind of knew the answer beforehand for this expression and so I put them in the question formulation, however, I have some other tedious expressions for which I do not know the end result...please let me know if I am not clear enough..thanks again

Comment: @Stoc See if the second way does what you're after.  You might want something in between, but I don't know how to do that automatically.  If you have a basis in mind, you just have to be able to program it (for `qs`).